# Populating multidimensional array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to populate a multidimensional array that matches the structure of another array.

I have one array initilized in the following way:

```
static char frequencyEn[][7] =
{
  ['A'] = ".082",
  ['B'] = ".015",
  ['C'] = ".028",
  ['D'] = ".043",
  ['E'] = ".127",
  ['F'] = ".022",
  ['G'] = ".020",
  ['H'] = ".061",
  ['I'] = ".070",
  ['J'] = ".002",
  ['K'] = ".008",
  ['L'] = ".040",
  ['M'] = ".024",
  ['N'] = ".067",
  ['O'] = ".075",
  ['P'] = ".019",
  ['Q'] = ".001",
  ['R'] = ".060",
  ['S'] = ".063",
  ['T'] = ".091",
  ['U'] = ".028",
  ['V'] = ".010",
  ['W'] = ".024",
  ['X'] = ".002",
  ['Y'] = ".020",
  ['Z'] = ".0O1"
};
```

This array holds values of average letter frequencies in english language. The second array I am trying to initilize and populate will hold the actual letter frequencies of a supplied text.

The eventual goal is to compare the values of two different arrays. I'm not yet working on the code that will compare the two arrays--only the part where I populate a second array with the counted values.

Letter frequency of a string is counted in this way. How can I initialize a new array and populate it with these letter frequency values? I am looking to create an array with the same structure as the previously presented array:

```
char *count(char *eText)
{
  char * cryptText = "Some encrypted text.";
  char string[100];
  int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
  int accum = 0;

  while ( cryptText[c] != '\0' )
   {

      if ( cryptText[c] >= 'a' && cryptText[c] <= 'z' ){
         count[cryptText[c]-'a']++;
         accum++;
      }

      else if (cryptText[c] >= 'A' && cryptText[c] <= 'Z'){
          count[cryptText[c]-'A']++;
          accum++;
      }
      c++;
   }

   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( count[c] != 0 )
          printf( "%c %f\n", c +'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);
   }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can populate a new array with the same structure as the first array. Currently, the code gives me this type of printed output:

```
b 0.103448
c 0.034483
d 0.034483
e 0.034483
g 0.034483
i 0.068966
j 0.068966
k 0.068966
l 0.034483
n 0.034483
p 0.034483
q 0.137931
r 0.103448
s 0.034483
u 0.034483
v 0.034483
x 0.034483
z 0.068966
```

How can I add these values to an array in this way:

```
char frequencyCurrent[][]=
{
    ['A'] = ".000",
    ['B'] = ".103"
    ...
}
```

In case it is helpful to see things in context, this is more code to show how the initialized array is used:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * cryptText = 0;

static char clef[][7] =
{
  ['A'] = "X",
  ['B'] = "Y",
  ['C'] = "Z",
  ['D'] = "A",
  ['E'] = "B",
  ['F'] = "C",
  ['G'] = "D",
  ['H'] = "E",
  ['I'] = "F",
  ['J'] = "G",
  ['K'] = "H",
  ['L'] = "I",
  ['M'] = "J",
  ['N'] = "K",
  ['O'] = "L",
  ['P'] = "M",
  ['Q'] = "N",
  ['R'] = "O",
  ['S'] = "P",
  ['T'] = "Q",
  ['U'] = "R",
  ['V'] = "S",
  ['W'] = "T",
  ['X'] = "U",
  ['Y'] = "V",
  ['Z'] = "W"

};

static char frequencyEn[][7] =
{
  ['A'] = ".082",
  ['B'] = ".015",
  ['C'] = ".028",
  ['D'] = ".043",
  ['E'] = ".127",
  ['F'] = ".022",
  ['G'] = ".020",
  ['H'] = ".061",
  ['I'] = ".070",
  ['J'] = ".002",
  ['K'] = ".008",
  ['L'] = ".040",
  ['M'] = ".024",
  ['N'] = ".067",
  ['O'] = ".075",
  ['P'] = ".019",
  ['Q'] = ".001",
  ['R'] = ".060",
  ['S'] = ".063",
  ['T'] = ".091",
  ['U'] = ".028",
  ['V'] = ".010",
  ['W'] = ".024",
  ['X'] = ".002",
  ['Y'] = ".020",
  ['Z'] = ".0O1"
};

enum { MAX_CLEF = sizeof(clef) / sizeof(clef[0]) };

static char *prompt(FILE *fp, const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
  printf("%s", prompt);
  fflush(0);
  return fgets(buffer, buflen, fp);
}

static void substitute(FILE *fp, const char *buffer, const char *pad1, const char *pad2)
{
  int c;
  const char *pad = pad1;
  int col = 0;
  for (int i = 0; (c = buffer[i]) != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (col == 0)
    {
      fputs(pad, fp);
      col += strlen(pad);
      pad = pad2;
    }

    col++;
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c < MAX_CLEF && clef[c][0] != '\0')
    {
      fputs(clef[c], fp);
      col += strlen(clef[c]);
    }
    else
    {
      putc(c, fp);
      col++;
    }
    if (col > 72)
    {
      putc('\n', fp);
      col = 0;
    }
  }
}

char *count(char *eText)
{
  char string[100];
  int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
  int accum = 0;
  char *frequencies[2]

  while ( cryptText[c] != '\0' )
   {

      if ( cryptText[c] >= 'a' && cryptText[c] <= 'z' ){
         count[cryptText[c]-'a']++;
         accum++;
      }

      else if (cryptText[c] >= 'A' && cryptText[c] <= 'Z'){
          count[cryptText[c]-'A']++;
          accum++;
      }
      c++;
   }

   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( count[c] != 0 )
          printf( "%c %f\n", c +'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);
   }
}


int main(void)
{
  char * buffer = 0;

  long length;
  FILE * plainTextFile = fopen ("plaintext.txt", "rb");
  FILE * cipherTextFile = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "w+");

  if (plainTextFile)
  {
    fseek (plainTextFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (plainTextFile);
    fseek (plainTextFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc (length);
    if (buffer)
    {
      fread (buffer, 1, length, plainTextFile);
    }
    fclose (plainTextFile);
  }

  if (buffer)
  {
    printf("%s", buffer);
  }
  else {
    printf("failure");
  }

  substitute(cipherTextFile, buffer, "", "     ");

  if (cipherTextFile)
  {
    fseek (cipherTextFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (cipherTextFile);
    fseek (cipherTextFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    cryptText = malloc (length);
    if (cryptText)
    {
      fread (cryptText, 1, length, cipherTextFile);
    }
    fclose (cipherTextFile);
  }

  if (cryptText)
  {
    printf("%s", cryptText);
  }
  else {
    printf("failure");
  }

}
```

Comment: Populate what array? This question is unclear. What do you want to do?

Comment: The `frequencyEn` array looks really odd. What problem are you trying to solve with it? It's also never used in the following code you've shown.

Comment: @5gon12eder I'm interested in knowing how it is odd and what I can do to improve it. I'm new to C. See edits

Comment: So essentially, you want to *copy* an array? A doubly nested `for` loop (or a more efficient `memcpy` call) could do that for you. I've called `frequencyEn` odd because it looks like you're trying to store floating-point numbers as character strings which is not exactly straight-forward.

Comment: @user25976: it's odd because you declare it and never use it.  What is it for?  What do you want to do?

Comment: @ChrisDodd The array I declared holds values of average letter frequencies in english language. The second array I am trying to initilize and populate will hold the actual letter frequencies of a supplied text. I'm not working on the code yet that will compare the previous array--just the part where I populate a second array with the counted values.

Comment: Any reason you use string literals for frequency or replacement character? Why not use an array of `struct`s?

Comment: @Olaf I'm new to C and was not aware of the benefits of doing so. How does the struct s work better? How would that look?

Comment: Please understand this is no tutoring site. You are expected to do some research on your own. Any C book will show those basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predefined array you have is not very usable.  You store floating point values as strings, and the index of the array goes from 0 to the ASCII value of 'Z' instead of 0 to 25.

Instead, define `frequencyEn` like this:

```
double frequencyEn[] = { 
    .082, .015, .028, .043, .127, .022, 
    .020, .061, .070, .002, .008, .040, 
    .024, .067, .075, .019, .001, .060, 
    .063, .091, .028, .010, .024, .002, 
    .020, .001 };
```

You can then compare as follows:

```
if (frequencyEn[c] == ((double)count[c] / accum))
```

However, floating point math is not exact, so you instead need to check if it's "close"

```
if (fabs(frequencyEn[c] - ((double)count[c] / accum)) < 0.00001)
```

Comment: that's good insight on how to eventually compare the values of the two arrays. I'm still wondering, however, how to get an array that would be structured double frequencyCurrent[] = {.010, .345, ...} where the values are ((double)count[c] / accum))

Comment: @user25976 In that case, define `count` as an array of `double`, then divide each element by `accum` after you've read the text.

Comment: because of the alphabet substitution, count[c] won't be close to frequencyEn[c]. Is there a way to compare the two arrays and determine the way in which the alphabet was shifted?